# Search functionality with Edit Text on CustomView ListView

Tags: android, listview, search, android-edittext

I am able to filter out my custom list.

Issue is my custom listview has 4 text fields.
When I search I get the result but if I have some repeated text in different fields of my list row, then the filter returns same number of duplicate rows.

if say, my entries are these 2 rows with data {apple, apple, orange, apple},{grapes, melon, mango, peaches}
and I start searching for apple... I will see 3 rows with duplicate data in my list view instead of one

How can I stop this duplication?

here is my code:

```
adapter = new MyAdapter(
            this,
            list,
            R.layout.list_row,
            new String[] {fruit1, fruit2, fruit3, fruit4 },
            new int[] {R.id.fruit1, R.id.fruit2, R.id.fruit3,R.id.fruit4});

    populateList();
    setListAdapter(adapter);

    search.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence cs, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
            // When user changed the Text
            ListScreen.this.adapter.getFilter().filter(cs);   
        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {}

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {}
    });

  class MyAdapter extends SimpleAdapter{

    public PassAdapter(Context context, List<? extends Map<String, ?>> data, int resource,  String[] from, int[] to) {
        super(context, data, resource, from, to);
        }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View view =  super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
        arrow = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.arrow);
        data= (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.data);

        arrow.setImageResource(R.drawable.arrow_down);
        data.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        return view;
    }
```

Here is my custom filter code as well
But this does not refresh my list

```
    @Override
    public Filter getFilter() {

        Filter filter = new Filter() {

            @Override
            protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
                FilterResults res = new FilterResults();
                // We implement here the filter logic
                if (constraint == null || constraint.length() == 0) {
                    // No filter implemented we return all the list
                    res.values = tempList;
                    res.count = tempList.size();
                } else {
                    synchronized(this){
                        // We perform filtering operation
                        List<HashMap<String, String>> dataList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
                        for (HashMap<String, String> data : tempList) {
                            if (data.get("fruit1").toUpperCase().startsWith(constraint.toString().toUpperCase()))
                                dataList.add(data);
                        }

                        res.values = dataList;
                        res.count = dataList.size();

                    }
                }
                return res;
            }

            @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
            @Override
            protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
                 if (results.count == 0)
                        notifyDataSetInvalidated();
                    else {
                        tempList = (ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>) results.values;
                        notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }

            }
        };
        return filter;
    }
```

Comment: You might want to paste `MyAdapter` code as well.

Comment: added the adapter code :)

Comment: I suggest you write your own custom [Filter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Filter.html) - the default implementation does clearly not suit your needs.

Comment: I added custom filter but the screen is not refreshing!!
While debugging I can see data getting filtered out but on UI nothing happens !!

Comment: Update your question with new code. Also, make sure you're filtering properly - maybe follow this [example](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.4.2_r1/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.java#ArrayAdapter.ArrayFilter)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

found a work around

```
  search.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence cs, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
            // When user changed the Text
//                ListScreen.this.adapter.getFilter().filter(cs); 
            if(cs.length() == 0 || cs == null){
                list.clear();
                list.addAll(origList);
            }
            else{
                ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> temp = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();
                for(HashMap<String, String> data : list){
                    if(data.get("fruit1").toLowerCase().contains(cs.toString().toLowerCase())){
                        temp.add(data);
                    }
                }
                list.clear();
                list.addAll(temp);
            }
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {}

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {}
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

In mainactivity;

```
  etsearch.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

                    String text = etsearch.getText().toString().toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault());
                if(text.length()>2)
                subCropAdapter.filter(text);
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

            }
        });
```

And In adapter;

public void filter(String charText) {

```
    charText = charText.toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault());

    subCropModelList.clear();
    if (charText.length() == 0) {

        subCropModelList.addAll(subCropModelArrayList);

    } else {
        for (SubCropModel wp : subCropModelArrayList) {
            if (wp.getSubCropName().toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault()).contains(charText)) {
                subCropModelList.add(wp);
                //subCropModelArrayList.add(wp);
            }

        }

        subCropModelArrayList.clear();
        subCropModelArrayList.addAll(subCropModelList);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

I think your solution is simple

just add adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();  in the method onTextChanged.

Example:

```
search.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() { 
    @Override 
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence cs, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) { 
        // When user changed the Text 
        ListScreen.this.adapter.getFilter().filter(cs); 
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();   
    }
```

This would resolve the issue simply.

Comment: Doesn't `notifuDataSetChanged()` only work if `add()`, `insert()`, `remove()` or `clear()` is done on the Adapter?